# How to build URLs in Python with the standard library?

Tags: python

Many languages have standard APIs for building and parsing URLS from - or into parts like scheme, host, port, query-param. Some allow me to start with a base URL and add paths.

How do I do this in python using the standard library?
For example, how would I build the URL:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com?arg1=someargument&arg2=someotherargument
```

given a base of `"http://subdomain.domain.com"` and some query params. Or given the scheme: `"http"`, the host `"subdomain.domain.com"`, etc?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) in the python standard library is all about building valid urls. Check the documentation of urlparse

Example:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlencode, urlparse, urlunparse

# namedtuple to match the internal signature of urlunparse
Components = namedtuple(
    typename='Components', 
    field_names=['scheme', 'netloc', 'url', 'path', 'query', 'fragment']
)

query_params = {
    'param1': 'some data', 
    'param2': 42
}

url = urlunparse(
    Components(
        scheme='https',
        netloc='example.com',
        query=urlencode(query_params),
        path='',
        url='/',
        fragment='anchor'
    )
)

print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://example.com/?param1=some+data&param2=42#anchor
```

Comment: specifially [urlunparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunparse) or unsplit to build a url

Comment: urlparse has been moved to urllib.parse since python 3: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlparse

Comment: E.g. `urllib.parse.urlunparse(('http', 'example.com', '/path', None, 'a=1', 'fragment'))`.

Comment: This library only gives you the most primitive components to build a valid URL; you have to understand how to assemble those components. For example, urlunparse takes a "netloc" which is the "username:password@host:port", and you're on the hook for URL-encoding the password and string interpolating it into the "netloc" string (otherwise passwords containing common special characters will break your program). Similarly, you have to convert your query dict into a string, taking care to URL encode appropriately. If you're looking for a sane library for building valid URLs, this ain't it.

Comment: @Senthil Kumaran, can we convert dataframe output to URL. display dataframe table output in the form of url : any one can access it ?

Comment: If you put anything in the path parameter, this appears to generate a url with a semicolon before the path.

Answer (score 121):

I would go for Python's [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html), it's a built-in library.

**Python 2**

```
import urllib
url = 'https://example.com/somepage/?'
params = {'var1': 'some data', 'var2': 1337}
print(url + urllib.urlencode(params))
```

**Python 3**

```
import urllib.parse
url = 'https://example.com/somepage/?'
params = {'var1': 'some data', 'var2': 1337}
print(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(params))
```

Output:

```
https://example.com/somepage/?var1=some+data&var2=1337
```

Comment: urllib.urlencode(getVars)

Comment: don't concat strings with `+` in python. Try `"{}{}".format(url, querystring)`

Comment: I kind of agree, but it's a trade off. In this case I see nothing wrong with using + for concatenation, and since Python 2 there's not even a speed penalty of using +.
However if you want to fully comply with the PEP8 standard - and through that get the cross compatibility / stability, your better off using format(), append() and join().

Answer (score 28):

Here is an example of using `urlparse` to generate URLs. This provides the convenience of adding path to the URL without worrying about checking slashes.

```
import urllib.parse

def build_url(base_url, path, args_dict):
    # Returns a list in the structure of urlparse.ParseResult
    url_parts = list(urllib.parse.urlparse(base_url))
    url_parts[2] = path
    url_parts[4] = urllib.parse.urlencode(args_dict)
    return urllib.parse.urlunparse(url_parts)

>>> args = {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'}
>>> # works with double slash scenario
>>> build_url('http://www.example.com/', '/somepage/index.html', args)

http://www.example.com/somepage/index.html?arg1=value1&arg2=value2

# works without slash
>>> build_url('http://www.example.com', 'somepage/index.html', args)

http://www.example.com/somepage/index.html?arg1=value1&arg2=value2
```

Comment: I have been using a library called [yarl](https://yarl.readthedocs.io) and it works great with URLs. It is very pythonic and supports operator `/` to join paths just like `pathlib`.

Comment: thanks for yarl tip really convenient, should be somewhere in the answers as everything else is just bleh

Answer (score 16):

used suggestion of [Mark Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11389648/mark-johnson) to update, urlencode() is now under urllib.parse, added strip of trailing `/`

```py
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
    
    def make_url(base_url, *uris, **params):
        url = base_url.rstrip('/')
        for uri in uris:
            _uri = uri.strip('/')
            url = '{}/{}'.format(url, _uri) if _uri else url
        if params:
            url = '{}?{}'.format(url, urlencode(params))
        return url
```

Usage:

```py
>>>print(make_url('http://example.com', 'user', 'ivan', alcoholic='true', age=18))
http://example.com/user/ivan?age=18&alcoholic=true

>>>print(make_url('https://example.com/', '/', '/one/two/', '/', 'three/'))
https://example.com/one/two/three
```

Comment: I like this. I think it's worth stripping out leading and trailing `'/'` in `base_url` and `res` items. Also `urlencode()` is now under `urllib.parse` (as of Python 3 maybe?)