# Getting the next page when scraping an API

Tags: python-3.x, api, web-scraping

I am trying to use the pagination and go to the next page after finished scraping the current page. This is my first time scraping an API, so i am a bit lost and have not yet found anything on the internet.

Question: What do i need to do to get to the next page

API: https://games.crossfit.com/competitions/api/v1/competitions/open/2018/leaderboards?division=2&region=0&scaled=0&sort=0&occupation=0&page=1

Code (what i have so far):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import json

url = 'https://games.crossfit.com/competitions/api/v1/competitions/open/2018/leaderboards?division=1&region=0&scaled=0&sort=0&occupation=0&page=1'

nameList = []
genderList = []
regionList = []
gymList = []
ageList = []
heightList = []
weightList = []
ordList = []
overallList = []
overallScoreList = []

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)

year = parsed['competition']['year']
comp = parsed['competition']['competitionType']
year = parsed['competition']['year']
board = parsed['leaderboardRows']
for all in board:
    name = all['entrant']['competitorName']
    gender = all['entrant']['gender']
    region = all['entrant']['regionName']
    gym = all['entrant']['affiliateName']
    age = all['entrant']['age']
    overall = all['overallRank']
    overallS = all['overallScore']
    height = all['entrant']['height']
    weight = all['entrant']['weight']

    nameList.append(name)
    genderList.append(gender)
    regionList.append(region)
    gymList.append(gym)
    ageList.append(age)
    heightList.append(height)
    weightList.append(weight)
    overallList.append(overall)
    overallScoreList.append(overallS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and easy way would be something like below:

```
import requests

url = 'https://games.crossfit.com/competitions/api/v1/competitions/open/2018/leaderboards?division=1&region=0&scaled=0&sort=0&occupation=0&page={}'

for link in [url.format(page) for page in range(1,5)]:
    response = requests.get(link)
    for item in response.json()['leaderboardRows']:
        name = item['entrant']['competitorName']
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

The crossfit API provides all necessary information in the `pagination` section. It gives you something like this:

```
"pagination":
    {
        "currentPage":1,
        "totalPages":3440,
        "totalCompetitors":171977
    },
```

To get pages other than 1, you need to change the GET parameter in the url:
Instead of `&page=1`, write `&page=2`. Preferably, build your url using a function that you can pass relevant parameters, e.g.
url_for_page(20) would return
`https://games.crossfit.com/competitions/api/v1/competitions/open/2018/leaderboards?division=2&region=0&scaled=0&sort=0&occupation=0&page=20`

I hope you find that helpful.

Comment: thats the problem i am having. i am not 100% sure how to add the url to increase to 2.

Comment: @Ezzy I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799696/library-to-build-urls-in-python answers that part of your question.