# How do I redirect from one flask app to another flask app with url parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, redirect, flask-restful

I have a Python application in which for one specific API, I am trying to redirect it to another API present in another Flask application. To achieve this, I am using the below code:
`

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello_name(name):
    return redirect("http://localhost:8000/hello", 302)
```

`

Now, if I try to access my API by appending query parameters like `http://localhost:6000/hello?name=Sidharth`, it should be redirected to `http://localhost:8000/hello?name=Sidharth`. Can I get an advice on how this can be done?

I looked online and found that most of the posts are advising usage of url_for() but since I don't want to redirect to another view, I don't think url_for() will be beneficial in my case. With the code that I have written now, the query parameters are not being added to the redirected url.

Comment: How to build an external URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28011983/5378816

Answer (score -1):

Try to use HTTP status code 307 Internal Redirect instead of 302 like below:-

```
@app.route('/hello/')
def hello_name(name):
    return redirect(url_for('http://localhost:8000/hello', args1=name), code=307)
```

Comment: It is not an internal redirect. I am trying to access another flask application deployed in another hyperscaler. And I have the required url path, I just need to capture and forward the dynamic url query parameters. And the query parameters are optional.

Comment: did you tried above code snippet